# Simulink large scale modeling: best practices for interconnecting blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

What are the best practices for large scale modeling in Simulink when it comes to connecting blocks? Would you use the same structure for all I/O ports of your blocks to facilitate their interconnection (but obviously there will be a lot of redundant signals) or would you define custom structures for each I/O port type with only the necessary information?

For example:
A reactor is modeled as a single block with 4 inputs and 1 output:

- I1. Feed which is a structure containing: Flow and Concentrations (7 species);
- I2. Mass flow of enzymes - scalar;
- I3. Mass flow of water - scalar;
- I4. Outflow - which is adjusted by a controller to keep a constant mass in the tank - scalar;
- O1. The outstream, which is a struct: Flow and Concentrations
  (let's say 10 species).

Now imagine this reactor block is only a tiny piece of an entire process. There are enzymes and water tanks connected to it and some other downstream processes etc.

Would you use a unique structure for all IO ports (even if it scales up to 50-100 components but you would need less per block or 1 component like I2, I3 and I4 above which are scalars)? Is this regarded as bad programming practice?

Or would you customize the IO port structure for each block? Of course you would group them somehow and make reuse of them but with no redundant information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following useful: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/videos/tips-and-tricks-for-large-scale-model-based-design-part-2-81873.html.

I would personally use a single bus input and a single bus output for your reactor block. You can then group buses together to form larger bus signals as you move up the hierarchy of your model. Look at the Bus Creator and Bus Selector blocks.

Comment: Would you follow the SISO approach for all your blocks? I mean by SISO single input bus, single output bus, which would be structures of structures in the end.

Comment: I guess it depends how many signals you have going in and out of each block, but it is a very scalable approach and all of the large-scale models I dealt with used buses in one way or another.